# Cannot generate web service schema in Acumatica ERP System

Tags: web-services, acumatica, erp

I've created web service ID for generating web service schema like the following screenshot.

[image]

But I got the following error
[image]

And also I've tried to unpublish the customization project and regenerate webservice schema but it still the same thing.
[image]

[image]

I try to generate the web service schema directly to the current screen, but it shows the following error.
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks

** note: I use Acumatica ERP Version 17.207.0029 and include customization for the current instance.

Comment: Try to generate web service from the screen directly, if that works then you can use it, if not then unpublish packages and try again.

Comment: How if I need to generate schema from additional screen included of the package also if I should to unpublish the package ?

Comment: Go to Bills and Adjustment screen, in the top right corner you see one button Tools, from the Tools click on Web Service, this will generate web service for your screen. Repeat this process for each screen which you want to include in web service.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but still got the error. Please see my updated question above.